# Is `namedtuple` really as efficient in memory usage as tuples? My test says NO

Tags: python, memory, collections, tuples, namedtuple

It is stated in the Python documentation that one of the advantages of `namedtuple` is that it is as *memory-efficient* as tuples.

To validate this, I used iPython with [ipython_memory_usage](https://github.com/ianozsvald/ipython_memory_usage). The test is shown in the images below:

[image]
[image]

The test shows that:

- `10000000` instances of `namedtuple` used about `850 MiB` of RAM
- `10000000` `tuple` instances used around `73 MiB` of RAM
- `10000000` `dict` instances used around `570 MiB` of RAM

So `namedtuple` used **much more** memory than `tuple`! Even **more** than `dict`!!

What do you think? Where did I go wrong?

Comment: I don't have a clear answer to your question, but it's possible that the peephole optimizer noticed that your tuple is defined as a literal with immutable members and gave you back a list of references to the same tuple.

Comment: @Chinny84 -- Actually, I'm _really_ surprised that the dictionary takes less memory than a named-tuple.  I know that if you're working in python3.6, dictionaries have been upgraded with a new implementation that should be more memory efficient, but I still don't think that should beat a tuple...

Comment: @mgilson That's probably because the class returned by `namedtuple()` has some Python level attributes, on the other hand `dict` is still pure C.

Comment: Like mgilson mentioned, try to create the tuples dynamically. CPython can cache literals of immutable objects, unfortunately namedtuple doesn't have a literal and hence it can't be cached.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary -- What instance level attributes does it have though?  You can see the code used to generate a named tuple by passing `verbose=True` to the constructor... All of the attributes are defined at the class level -- And there's only one class no matter how many instances of it you make...

Comment: @mgilson: A quick check shows your hypothesis is correct. The construction of `(1, 2, 3)` gets constant-folded, and all `append` calls in the loop append the same tuple.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A simpler metric is to check the size of equivalent `tuple` and `namedtuple` objects.  Given two roughly analogous objects:

```
from collections import namedtuple
import sys

point = namedtuple('point', 'x y z')
point1 = point(1, 2, 3)

point2 = (1, 2, 3)
```

Get the size of them in memory:

```
>>> sys.getsizeof(point1)
72

>>> sys.getsizeof(point2)
72
```

They look the same to me...

---

Taking this a step further to replicate your results, notice that if you create a list of identical tuples the way you're doing it, each `tuple` is the exact same object:

```
>>> test_list = [(1,2,3) for _ in range(10000000)]
>>> test_list[0] is test_list[-1]
True
```

So in your list of tuples, each index contains a reference the *same* object.  There are not 10000000 tuples, there are 10000000 references to one tuple.

On the other hand, your list of `namedtuple` objects actually *does* create 10000000 unique objects.

A better apples-to-apples comparison would be to view the memory usage for

```
>>> test_list = [(i, i+1, i+2) for i in range(10000000)]
```

and:

```
>>> test_list_n = [point(x=i, y=i+1, z=i+2) for i in range(10000000)]
```

They have the same size:

```
>>> sys.getsizeof(test_list)
81528056

>>> sys.getsizeof(test_list_n)
81528056
```

Comment: Which interestingly is the same size as a dictionary:

    >>> test_list_d = [{"x":i, "y":i+1, "z":i+2} for i in range(10000000)]
    >>> sys.getsizeof(test_list_d)
    81528056

Comment: Thats because youre always just counting the size of a generator object and not the resulting data structure

Answer (score 10):

Doing some investigation myself (with Python 3.6.6). I run into following conclusions:

1. In all three cases (list of tuples, list of named tuples,  list of dicts). sys.getsizeof returns size of the list, which stores only references anyway. So you get size: 81528056 in all three cases.
2. Sizes of elementary types are:

   `sys.getsizeof((1,2,3))
   72`

   `sys.getsizeof(point(x=1, y=2, z=3))
   72`

   `sys.getsizeof(dict(x=1, y=2, z=3))
   240`
3. timing is very bad for named tuple:
   list of tuples: 1.8s
   list of named tuples: 10s
   list of dicts: 4.6s
4. Looking to system load I become suspicious about results from getsizeof.
   After measuring the footprint of the Ptyhon3 process I get:

   `test_list = [(i, i+1, i+2) for i in range(10000000)]`
   increase by:  1 745 564K
   that is about 175B per element

   `test_list_n = [point(x=i, y=i+1, z=i+2) for i in range(10000000)]`
   increase by: 1 830 740K
   that is about 183B per element

   `test_list_n = [point(x=i, y=i+1, z=i+2) for i in range(10000000)]`
   increase by: 2 717 492 K
   that is about 272B per element