# python: class vs tuple huge memory overhead (?)

Tags: python, list, class, data-structures, tuples

I'm storing a lot of complex data in tuples/lists, but would prefer to use small wrapper classes to make the data structures easier to understand, e.g.

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, first, last):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last

p = Person('foo', 'bar')
print(p.last)
...
```

would be preferable over

```
p = ['foo', 'bar']
print(p[1])
...
```

*however* there seems to be a horrible memory overhead:

```
l = [Person('foo', 'bar') for i in range(10000000)]
# ipython now taks 1.7 GB RAM
```

and

```
del l
l = [('foo', 'bar') for i in range(10000000)]
# now just 118 MB RAM
```

Why? is there any obvious alternative solution that I didn't think of?

Thanks!

(I know, in this example the 'wrapper' class looks silly. But when the data becomes more complex and nested, it is more useful)

Comment: `collections.namedtuple` seem like they are made for this purpose, but they take around `1.1GB` for your example. Not much better.

Comment: Looks into `__slots__` or move to Python 3 for [key-sharing dictionary](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0412/).

Comment: In the case of tuples, I believe it just references the same tuple 10 million times. When you create an object, either class or a new tuple, it uses a lot more memory

Comment: As indicated in the answers, your tuple example only creates a single tuple object.  You should create a test case where you create a lot of *different* tuples vs custom objects and see how the performance is.

Comment: try randomizing the values, you should get a different result.

Comment: Related: [Is `namedtuple` really as efficient in memory usage as tuples? My test says NO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41003081/846892)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As others have said in their answers, you'll have to generate different objects for the comparison to make sense.

So, let's compare some approaches.

#### `tuple`

```
l = [(i, i) for i in range(10000000)]
# memory taken by Python3: 1.0 GB
```

#### `class Person`

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, first, last):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last

l = [Person(i, i) for i in range(10000000)]
# memory: 2.0 GB
```

#### `namedtuple` (`tuple` + `__slots__`)

```
from collections import namedtuple
Person = namedtuple('Person', 'first last')

l = [Person(i, i) for i in range(10000000)]
# memory: 1.1 GB
```

`namedtuple` is basically a class that extends `tuple` and uses `__slots__` for all named fields, but it adds fields getters and some other helper methods (you can see the exact code generated if called with `verbose=True`).

#### `class Person` + `__slots__`

```
class Person:
    __slots__ = ['first', 'last']
    def __init__(self, first, last):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last

l = [Person(i, i) for i in range(10000000)]
# memory: 0.9 GB
```

This is a trimmed-down version of `namedtuple` above. A clear winner, even better than pure tuples.

Comment: Thanks for the nice overview! I case anyone wonders how 2*10M integers can take up 1000M of memory, this seems to be due to the containing list + references: `import numpy as np` `l = np.array([(i, i) for i in range(10000000)])` will only take 189MB (after taking 1GB for a short time during construction). This doesn't work with the class instances though (references?).

Comment: Actually, `np.array([(i, i) for i in range(10000000)])` will create a homogeneous 2-D array, `10000000x2`, of `dtype('int64')`, meaning the size of such array is `~ 8 x N_elem` bytes, or in this case `~160 MB`.

Answer (score 7):

Using `__slots__` decreases the memory footprint quite a bit (from 1.7 GB to 625 MB in my test), since each instance no longer needs to hold a `dict` to store the attributes.

```
class Person:
    __slots__ = ['first', 'last']
    def __init__(self, first, last):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
```

The drawback is that you can no longer add attributes to an instance after it is created; the class only provides memory for the attributes listed in the `__slots__` attribute.

Comment: I've corrected what I thought was a 'typo' in you answer, please rollback with my apologies if it wasn't.

Comment: No, the correction was valid. It's the instance of `Person` to which you can no longer add new attributes. You probably can't added attributes to `first` or `last`, either, but for entirely different reasons :)

Answer (score 2):

There is yet another way to reduce the amount of memory occupied by objects by turning off support for cyclic garbage collection in addition to turning off `__dict__` and `__weakref__`. It is implemented in the library [recordclass](https://bitbucket.org/intellimath/recordclass):

```
$ pip install recordclass

>>> import sys
>>> from recordclass import dataobject, make_dataclass
```

Create the class:

```
class Person(dataobject):
   first:str
   last:str
```

or

```
>>> Person = make_dataclass('Person', 'first last')
```

As result (python 3.9, 64 bit):

```
>>> print(sys.getsizeof(Person(100,100)))
32
```

For `__slot__` based class we have  (python 3.9, 64 bit):

```
class PersonSlots:
    __slots__ = ['first', 'last']
    def __init__(self, first, last):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last

>>> print(sys.getsizeof(Person(100,100)))
48
```

As a result more saving of memory is possible.

For `dataobject`-based:

```
l = [Person(i, i) for i in range(10000000)]
memory size: 409 Mb
```

For `__slots__`-based:

```
  l = [PersonSlots(i, i) for i in range(10000000)]
  memory size: 569 Mb
```

Answer (score -1):

In your second example, you only create one object, because tuples are constants.

```
>>> l = [('foo', 'bar') for i in range(10000000)]
>>> id(l[0])
4330463176
>>> id(l[1])
4330463176
```

Classes have the overhead, that the attributes are saved in a dictionary. Therefore namedtuples needs only half the memory.

Comment: While it's true that tuples are constants, that doesn't explain the difference here. `[tuple(['foo', 'bar']) for i in range(N)]` creates N constant (but distinct) tuple objects.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the reason is not simply because "tuples are constant". It basically a CPython optimization that works on some kind of tuple literals, for example `(1, 2 , 3/1)` won't result in same ID in CPython 2, because 3/1 can't be constant folded in CPython 2.