# What is the difference between namedtuple and 'type' function

Tags: python, namedtuple

I recently visited a forum with python tricks and came across this:

```
>>> Points = type("Points", (object,), {'x' : None, 'y' : None})
>>> Player = Points()
>>> Player.x = 23
>>> Player.y = 54
>>> Player.x
23
>>> Player.y - Player.x
31
...
```

This syntax reminds me of the named tuples syntax:

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> Points = namedtuple("Points", ['x', 'y'])
>>> Player = Points(
    x = 23,
    y = 54
)
>>> Player.x
23
>>> Player.y - Player.x
21
...
```

And I can't understand how they differ except that named tuples can't be changed and have indexing. What advantages have named tuples and type function and what is better to use in our projects?

Comment: `type` is the base metaclass used to construct all types (classes) in Python. `namedtuple` is a function that returns types with very specific behavior. I'm sure it uses `type` internally to do what it does, but as a practical matter it is like a more limited version of `type` that only makes a certain kind of class.

Answer (score 0):

Let's dive into the source code!

First, we'll take a look at the definition of [`namedtuple`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2085bd0877e17ad4d98a4586d5eabb6faecbb190/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L313):

```py
result = type(typename, (tuple,), class_namespace)
```

`class_namespace` contains the field names:

```py
    for index, name in enumerate(field_names):
        doc = _sys.intern(f'Alias for field number {index}')
        class_namespace[name] = _tuplegetter(index, doc)
```

`namedtuple` essentially creates an object, derived from `tuple`, wheres your first example creates an object from the base `object`.

#### Conclusion

You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45123561/695377) to see the difference in memory between the two.
It's up to you to decide which one to use, based on readability and other stuff you would like to use with that object. I would say that based on the answer above, looking at your example code, I would go with `namedtuple` (Or the [`typing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) version of it which is even cooler!:

```py
class Employee(NamedTuple):
    name: str
    id: int
```

)