# How can I properly hash dictionaries with a common set of keys, for deduplication purposes?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some log data like:

```
logs = [
 {'id': '1234', 'error': None, 'fruit': 'orange'},
 {'id': '12345', 'error': None, 'fruit': 'apple'}
]
```

Each dict has the same keys: `'id'`, `'error'` and `'fruit'` (in this example).

I want to [remove duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961363) from this list, but straightforward `dict` and `set` based approaches do not work because my elements are themselves `dict`s, which are [not hashable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151658):

```
>>> set(logs)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

Another approach is to [sort and use itertools.groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213923) - but dicts are also not comparable, so this also does not work:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> [k for k, _ in groupby(sorted(logs))]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'dict'
```

I had the idea to calculate a hash value for each log entry, and store it in a `set` for comparison, like so:

```
def compute_hash(log_dict: dict):
    return hash(log_dict.values())

def deduplicate(logs):
    already_seen = set()
    for log in logs:
        log_hash = compute_hash(log)
        if log_hash in already_seen:
            continue
        already_seen.add(log_hash)
        yield log
```

However, I found that `compute_hash` would give the same hash for different dictionaries, even ones with completely bogus contents:

```
>>> logs = [{'id': '123', 'error': None, 'fruit': 'orange'}, {}]
>>> # The empty dict will be removed; every dict seems to get the same hash.
>>> list(deduplicate(logs))
[{'id': '123', 'error': None, 'fruit': 'orange'}]
```

After some experimentation, I was seemingly able to fix the problem by modifying `compute_hash` like so:

```
def compute_hash(log_dict: dict):
    return hash(frozenset(log_dict.values()))
```

However, I cannot understand why this makes a difference. **Why** did the original version seem to give the same hash for every input dict? Why does converting the `.values` result to a `frozenset` first fix the problem?
Aside from that: **is this algorithm correct**? Or is there some counterexample where the wrong values will be removed?

---

<sub>This question discusses how hashing works in Python, in depth, as well as considering other data structures that might be more appropriate than dictionaries for the list elements. See [List of unique dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11092511) instead if you simply want to remove duplicates from a list of dictionaries.</sub>

Comment: @JohnGordon The input to the function is the individual dictionary in the `logs` list not the `logs` list itself.

Comment: You could convert the dictionaries to `NamedTuple`. Then you can call the built-in `hash()` function, or put them in a `set`.

Comment: Why do you use `hash`? To save memory?

Comment: @KellyBundy Yes. There  are a lot of logs. Also interested in knowing any alternative approaches as well.

Comment: a hash collision will happen for any container using any algorithm, you can't stop it, that's why dictionaries and sets also use equality to check if two items are the same, anyway if you really care about the size then you should probably code it in something like C++, or rust, python is very wasteful when it comes to memory, maybe even use a disk mapped set/hashmap in them for extra space.

Comment: Would it be a memory *problem* If you kept the different log dicts in memory? How many do you have? Are they much bigger than what you've shown here?

Comment: Would you mind terribly if I edit the post to: a) decontextualize the problem a bit from your specific requirements; b) give context on the underlying problem (i.e., show that simply storing the dicts in a set directly isn't possible); c) simplify and focus the question; d) add reference links for existing questions (e.g. about deduplicating lists in general)?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### What went wrong

The first thing I want to point out about the original attempt is that it seems over-engineered. When the inputs are hashable, manually iterating is only necessary [to preserve order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214), and even then, in 3.7 and up we can rely on the order-preserving property of `dict`s.

#### Just because it's hashable doesn't mean the hash is useful

It also isn't especially useful to call `hash` on `log_dict.values()`. While `log_dict` is not hashable, its `.values()` (in 3.x) is an instance of the `dict_values` type (the name is not defined in the builtins, but that is how instances identify themselves), which **is** hashable:

```
>>> dv = {1:2, 3:4}.values()
>>> dv
dict_values([2, 4])
>>> {dv}
{dict_values([2, 4])}
```

So we could just as easily have used the `.values()` directly as a "hash":

```
def compute_hash(log_dict: dict):
    return log_dict.values()
```

... but this would have given a new bug - now every hash would be **different**:

```
>>> {1:2}.values() == {1:2}.values()
False
```

#### But why?

Because `dict_values` type doesn't define `__hash__`, nor `__eq__`. `object` is the immediate superclass, so calls to those methods fall back to the `object` defaults:

```
>>> dv.__class__.__bases__
(<class 'object'>,)
>>> dv.__class__.__hash__
<slot wrapper '__hash__' of 'object' objects>
>>> dv.__class__.__eq__
<slot wrapper '__eq__' of 'object' objects>
```

In fact, `dict_values` cannot sensibly implement these methods because **it is (indirectly) mutable** - as a view, it is dependent on the underlying dict:

```
>>> d = {1:2}
>>> dv = d.values()
>>> d[3] = 4
>>> dv
dict_values([2, 4])
```

Since there isn't an obvious generic way to hash any object that also isn't exceedingly slow, while also caring about its actual attributes, the default simply *doesn't* care about attributes and is simply based on object identity. For example, on my platform, the results look like:

```
Python 3.8.10 (default, Nov 14 2022, 12:59:47) 
[GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> dv = {1:2, 3:4}.values()
>>> bin(id(dv))
'0b11111110101110011010010110000001010101011110000'
>>> bin(hash(dv))
'0b1111111010111001101001011000000101010101111'
```

In other words:

```
>>> hash(dv) == id(dv) // 16
True
```

Thus, if `compute_hash` in the original code is repeatedly called with temporary objects, it won't give useful results - the results don't depend on the contents of the object, and will commonly be the same, as temporary (i.e., immediately GCd) objects in a loop will often end up in the same memory location.

(Yes, this means that objects default to being hashable and equality-comparable. The `dict` type itself overrides `__hash__` to explicitly disallow it, while - curiously - overriding `__eq__` to compare contents.)

#### `frozenset` has a useful hash

On the other hand, `frozenset` is intended for long-term storage of some immutable data. Consequently, it's important and useful for it to define a `__hash__`, and it does:

```
>>> f = frozenset(dv)
>>> bin(id(f))
'0b11111110101110011010001011101000110001011100000'
>>> bin(hash(f))
'0b101111010001101001001111100001000001100111011101101100000110001'
```

### Dictionaries, hashing and collision detection

Although there have been many tweaks and optimizations over the years, Pythons `dict` and `set` types are both fundamentally [based on hash tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114830). When a value is inserted, its hash is first computed (normally an integer value), and then that value is reduced (normally using modulo) into an index into the underlying table storage. Similarly, when a value is looked up, the hash is computed and reduced in order to determine where to look in the table for that value.

Of course, it is possible that some other value is already stored in that spot. There are multiple possible strategies for dealing with this (and last I checked, the literature is inconsistent about naming them). But most importantly for our purposes: when looking up a value in a `dict` by key, or checking for the presence of a value in a `set`, the container will also have to do equality checks after figuring out where to look, in order to confirm that the right thing has actually been found.

Consequently, **any approach that simply computes a hash manually, and naively associates those hashes with the original values, will fail**. It is easy for two of the input dicts to have the same computed hash value, *even if their contents are actually being considered*. For example, the hash of a `frozenset` [is based on an XOR of hashes for the elements](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/setobject.c#L684). So if two of our input dicts had all the same values *assigned to keys in a different order*, the hash would be the same:

```
>>> def show_hash(d):
...     return bin(hash(frozenset(d.values())))
... 
>>> show_hash({'id': '1', 'error': None, 'value': 'apple'})
'0b101010010100001000111001000001000111101111110100010000010101110'
>>> # Changing a value changes the hash...
>>> show_hash({'id': '1', 'error': None, 'value': 'orange'})
'0b11111111001000011101011001001011100010100100010010110000100100'
>>> # but rearranging them does not:
>>> show_hash({'id': '1', 'error': 'orange', 'value': None})
'0b11111111001000011101011001001011100010100100010010110000100100'
```

It's also possible for such a hash collision to occur by coincidence with totally unrelated values. It's extremely unlikely for 64-bit hashes (since this value will **not** be reduced and used as a hash table index, despite the name)

#### Fixing it explicitly

So, in order to have correct code, we would need to do our own checking afterwards, explicitly checking whether the value which hashed to something in our `already_seen` set was actually equal to previous values that had that hash. And there *could theoretically* be multiple of those, so we'd have to remember multiple values for each of those external hashes, perhaps by using a `dict` for `already_seen` instead. Something like:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def deduplicate(logs):
    already_seen = defaultdict(list)
    for log in logs:
        log_hash = compute_hash(log)
        if log in already_seen.get(log_hash, ()):
            continue
        already_seen[log_hash].append(log)
        yield log
```

Hopefully this immediately looks unsatisfactory. With this approach, we are essentially re-implementing the core logic of sets and dictionaries - we compute hashes ourselves, retrieve corresponding values from internal storage (`already_seen`) **and** then manually check for equality (`if log in ...`).

#### Looking at it from another angle

The reason we're doing all of this in the first place - looking for a hash value to represent the original dict in our own storage - is because the dict isn't hashable. But we could address that problem head-on, instead, by explicitly **converting** the data into a hashable form (that preserves all the information), rather than trying to *relate* a hashable value to the data.

In other words, let's **use a different type** to represent the data, rather than a `dict`.

Since all our input `dict`s have the same keys, the natural thing to do would be to convert those into the **attributes of a user-defined class**. In 3.7 and up, a simple, natural and explicit way to do this is using a [dataclass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html), like so:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Optional

@dataclass(frozen=True, slots=True)
class LogEntry:
    id: str
    error: Optional[str]
    fruit: str
```

It's not explained very well in the documentation, but using `frozen=True` (the main purpose is to make the instances immutable) will cause a `__hash__` to be generated as well, taking the fields into account as desired. Using `slots=True` causes `__slots__` to be generated for the type as well, [avoiding memory overhead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45123238).

From here, it's trivial to convert the existing logs:

```
logs = [LogEntry(**d) for d in logs]
```

And we can directly deduplicate with a `set`:

```
set(logs)
```

or, preserving order using a `dict` (in 3.7 and up):

```
list(dict.fromkeys(logs))
```

There are other options, of course. The simplest is to make a `tuple` from the `.values` - assuming each log dict has its keys *in the same order* (again, assuming Python 3.7 and up, where keys *have* an order), this preserves all the *useful* information - the `.keys` are just for convenience. Slightly more sophisticated, we could use `collections.namedtuple`:

```
from collections import namedtuple

LogEntry = namedtuple('LogEntry', 'id error fruit')
# from here, use the LogEntry type as before
```

This is simpler than the `dataclass` approach, but less explicit (and doesn't offer an elegant way to document field types).

Answer (score 6):

You have some working answers, but I think you may be overcomplicating things. Here's the quick fix I would have done on your original code.

```
logs = [
    {'id': '1234', 'error': None, 'fruit': 'orange'},
    {'id': '1234', 'error': None, 'fruit': 'orange'},
    {'id': '12345', 'error': None, 'fruit': 'apple'}, 
]

def get_values(log: dict):
    return tuple(log.values())

unique_logs = set(map(get_values, logs))
for log in unique_logs:
    print(log)
```

> ('12345', None, 'apple')
> ('1234', None, 'orange')

Comment: As written, this needs equal keys order, though. Maybe they have that, maybe they don't.

Comment: Good point, thanks for the catch. I'll leave it as an exercise for OP as domain knowledge can make that really easy to add.

Comment: I appreciate the simplicity of this approach, and it indirectly helped me organize my answer and explain the key points more clearly.

Comment: I wasn't sure if named tuple would be easier, or just have get_values explicitly pull the three fields we care about. Although I did like your dataclasses answer better as it automatically handled everything that could trip us up.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can't base "already seen" on just a hash. Hashes are smaller than the actual data but can have collisions, that is the tradeoff. Use hashes to group logs and then check for equality.
2. There will still be collisions.
3. Dicts already group keys by hash and check equality for you, no need to reinvent this. Your logs are dictionaries, which are unhashable because they are mutable. One simple way could be to convert your dicts to strings using json.dumps(). Or for more efficient storage, implement a custom class with `__eq__()` and `__hash__()`.

```python
already_seen = set()
for log in logs:
    log_hash = json.dumps(log, sort_keys=True)
    if log_hash in already_seen:
        continue
    already_seen.add(log_hash)
```